# How do you select index of the list particular value?

Tags: java, appium

I have a list element and when user types 1 it clicks on index 0 element, when user types 2 it clicks on index 1 element, when user types 3  it selects index 2 element and when user types 4 it clicks on index 3 element.. How would you write the method in correct way?

AndroidFinBy(id="example")
   List list;

```
 public boolean list(int list_view) {

    if(list_view == 1) {
        list.get(0).click();
    }else if(list_view ==2){
        chipList.get(1).click();
    }else if(list_view ==3){
        list.get(2).click();
    }else if(list_view ==4){
         list.get(3).click();
    return true;
    }
    return false;
```

My code does not work keeps selecting the wrong element?

Comment: What are you asking? Is this a code review or do you have an issue with your code and if so what is it?

Comment: My code is not working and how would you write this method?

Comment: How should we know how it isn't working, if you want us to help you need to provide a clear and complete question. Does it return the wrong result, does it crash, ...?

Comment: It selects the wrong element ?

Comment: Again, you need to provide a clear description of what goes wrong not just one-liners, perhaps with an example. Update your question with this rather than posting more comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean list(int list_view) {
    if(list.size() >= list_view && list_view > 0) {
        list.get(list_view - 1).click();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Keeps selecting element with index 1. do you know why?